# Missing variables in Prestashop Order_conf email template

Tags: variables, prestashop

I am using version 1.7.6.3 of Prestashop, and I have a mail template called Order_conf. However, when I send the email, it does not display several variables.

The variables that are not being shown are:

[Email template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hlJe.png)

I have checked the OrderHistory.php file, and I found these two arrays:

Array 1:

```
$data = array(
    '{lastname}' => $result['lastname'],
    '{firstname}' => $result['firstname'],
    '{id_order}' => (int) $this->id_order,
    '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
    '{followup}' => str_replace('@', $order->getWsShippingNumber(), $carrierUrl),
    '{shipping_number}' => $order->getWsShippingNumber(),
);
```

Array 2:

```
$data = array(
    '{lastname}' => $customer->lastname,
    '{firstname}' => $customer->firstname,
    '{id_order}' => (int) $order->id,
    '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference(),
    '{nbProducts}' => count($virtual_products),
    '{virtualProducts}' => $links,
);
```

Interestingly, the missing variables in the email are not declared in either of these arrays. This might be the issue, but it's just a hypothesis.

I have reviewed the code and identified the arrays where the variables are populated, but it seems that the missing variables are not included in those arrays. My expectation is to find a solution or workaround to make the variables available in the Order_conf email template.

Answer (score 0):

These files:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.7.8.x/mails/_partials

they should be inside your /mails/es/ (or another lang) directory. They are probably missing, so you don't see variables being replaced.